# (Distance measured / height) * 100??? Is this correct?

Tags: normal-distribution, percentages, means, unit-of-measure, percentile

I have an exercise that tells me to face the wall and bend until my knees touches the wall without lifting my heel, then measure the max distance from my big toe to the wall without my raising my heel. the purpose of this exercise is to determine if there is a problem with my foot.

So if there are three of us who has done the exercise, with different height 5'9 (me), and two other friends who is 5'3 and 6'2. Is it reasonable to that I divide measurement result from the exercise over height * 100 ((exercise result / height) * 100) to get fair value where I can compare result to my friends.

I am not good with english, so forgive me if this looks confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a fair comparaison between you and your friend, you might want to compute the ratio:

$$ r = \frac{\text{Distance from big toe to heel}}{\text{Distance from heel to knee}} $$

This ratio is important if you want to compare your result with your friends. Ideally, you'd want to find a friend with a similar (close) ratio to yours.

Once you do that, measure the **shortest** (not the longest as mentioned in original post) distance to the wall for both you and your friend. Then you can divide those distances by your respective heights, this will give you two values you can compare.

As a final note, unless this is a purely theoric exercice, I would advise you not to overthink it and just wait to see what your doctor has to say about your results =)

EDIT : In the perspective of coding an app, here might be a good pseudo-code :

```
# get the user inputs
height = int(input())
feet = int(input())
shin = int(input())
distance_to_wall = int(input())

# Compute the ratio and index
ratio = shin/feet
index = distance_to_wall / height
```

From there, as you gather data you might want to plot a graph with x=ratio, y=index with mean values, healthy range, and so on.
You might also want to think about logging the date of the measurement so a user could see his progress as he's working on his foot condition.

Good luck =)

Comment: Thank you, so much for this. I am actually creating an app. That compares results from different people. Where height is not a factor and yes its all theoretical. So yeah.. I an just gathering inputs from you guys. If this is possible. thank you.

Comment: added some ideas in the context of your app

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much. What if I have 3 exercise that still measures distance from wall to toe. considering your suggestion, summing up all three exercise mean divided by no. of exercise ( three ) to determine if a person is has problems with their mobility. is it a sound judgment to make a point.

Comment: Can I average the mean of all three exercises and use it to compare it with others?

Comment: I think you might better compare the result of each exercices to a mean value for each of them. For example, let say, for an average person with ratio (length shin/ length feet) of 2.3, the average index is 0.18, then if a user input a ratio of 2.3, then you can compare his result with the 2.3 mean value. Those implies you have access to mean values across a certain population, ie : have a good number of measurements already.

Comment: I assumed when you said 3 exercices you meant three different exercices, in which case taking the mean of those three might not be relevant. BUT if by 3 exercices you meant 3 repetitions of the same exercice, then it's an excellent idea to take the mean value of those mesurements.

Comment: Ok, thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases.

If the result of this exercise is somewhat random for each person, then in this case, you would probably want to just take the mean, since you'd need more people to do any reasonable analysis.

If the result of this exercise is somewhat correlated to height, e.g. taller people get a bigger distance between their toe and the wall, then you might want to create a line of best fit $D(x)$ and measure other people against the line.

So in your case, you are assuming that height has nothing to do with the distance measurement, so if that is true, then what you're doing should be fine.

Comment: That was fast and thank you, I wanted to know how well I did where height is not a deciding factor. Thank you so much... Is it okay to ask more questions here without creating new topic. its still exercise related but with different metrics. Thank you so much.

Comment: yeah sure go ahead

Comment: I have 3 different exercise one mentioned above, and one that requires you to bend over where both hands clasped together and both middle fingers pointing at the bottom of the wall where your big toe is position inward. The third exercise is same as 2nd only your big toes is position outward. Again measuring the distance of from the wall to my big toe. getting the result of each exercise ((distance / height) * 100) , get the sum of all 3 exercise divided by 3 (no. of exercise). compare that the result to my friends, would that still tell me how well I did...

Comment: Ok, thank you for everything.